# Allowable ripple current οf battery charger

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, ripple

The ripple of the charging current is pretty important for the aging of an electric battery. So, the current ripple should be as less as possible. In order to reduce the current ripple, we have to use bigger values of inductances (For instance in a boost converter). So, there is a takeover between current ripple and the value of L.

I would like to ask about the maximum value of the current ripple (DI %) that it is chosen in a real application (such as Electric vehicle battery charger). A value of 2.5% current ripple is acceptable?

Comment: What sort of battery? Lead acid actually does better with pulse charging.

Comment: @Indraneel I am currently studying Li-ion batteries. The charging algorithm that I use is CC/CV

Comment: What does the battery's datasheet have to say about ripple current?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The datasheet doesn't provide any information about the ripple current.